# Cannot instantiate Configuration

Tags: java, user-interface, configuration, jframe

I am new to Java and this might seem like a basic question. I am trying to instantiate an object from a `javax.security.auth.login.Configuration` class, but Eclipse keeps telling me that it cannot instantiate the type `Configuration`.

```
private Configuration config = new Configuration();
```

Comment: "instantiate".  Believe Eclipse.  It's not clear where this class comes from, but my guess is that there is no default constructor available to you.

Comment: When you have a compiler error, it's important to post the exact error here, along with [a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try `Configuration.getConfiguration()`.

Answer (score 2):

`javax.security.auth.login.Configuration` is an `abstract class`.  I suggest that you look for a tutorial on how to use `javax.security`.